# JAX-RS with CXF without using Spring

Tags: java, servlets, cxf, jax-rs

I want to run a simple web application using CXF but not using spring. I was able to implement a Servlet using Jersey and now I'm trying out with CXF. Following is my web.xml.

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Output Socket</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JAXServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jaxrs.serviceClasses</param-name>
            <param-value>org.myCompany.servlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAXServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And in the pom.xml i have following dependencies.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I'm not sure about this configuration.

```
            <init-param>
                <param-name>jaxrs.serviceClasses</param-name>
                <param-value>org.myCompany.servlet</param-value>
            </init-param>
```

Once i deploy the war file in my tomcat I'm getting following exception.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.myCompany.servlet

Am I doing anything wrong here. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need the configuration below:

```
<init-param>
       <param-name>jaxrs.serviceClasses</param-name>
       <param-value>org.myCompany.servlet</param-value>
</init-param>
```

It's where you must mention your service classes. and the error says that it doesn't find the class **org.myCompany.servlet**. 
So be sure that your  service class exists with the good package and name.

Comment: i found the issue . It was a silly mistake. I have only put the package , not the full class path name. Reason I put that was I have two java classes in same package. Is there a way to mention only the package name ? And if you know can you please explain, do I need to have all those dependencies ? i just need a servlet backend to be run when an url is called

Comment: You cannot mention only the package name the full class name is required but you can list all your classes separated by a comma like this: org.myCompany.servlet.MyClass1, org.myCompany.servlet.MyClass2.... I am not sure you need  cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws dependency cause it's for the SOAP web services

Comment: hi I just tried with comma but it seems it won't recognize it as two classes. I'm getting that class not found exception again :(

Comment: put each class on a single line that ends with comma (except the last one) see [example](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-WithCXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet)

Comment: I did , and you cannot have spaces in between also because then it won't read after the space. I added like you have mentioned. But it says class not found for whole comma separated param-value :(

Comment: I have two classes and i put it like this <init-param>
            <param-name>jaxrs.serviceClasses</param-name>
            <param-value>org.myCompany.servlet.MyClass,org.myCompany.servlet.MyClass2</param-value> . So i have to put it in one line right. I did and it won't recognize.

Comment: jMounir i found the solution. you do not need a comma, I just put those two classes in two lines and it worked. Thanks for your help :)